# .NET Core 2.1 using environment variables for build using git hash in dotnet core command CLI

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface, asp.net-core-2.0, git-rev-parse

How to embed git hash to use in `dotnet build` command to be able to catch it and put in build pipeline process as an environment variable `${hash}` and use `${hash}` environment variable in appsettings..json files for ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable Git version information in your assembly, a good option is to use utilities like [NerdBank.GitVersioning](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning). It allows you to automatically calculate the version number based on the number of Git commits, include the Git commit SHA hash, and more.

You can [use the nbgv .NET CLI tool](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/master/doc/nbgv-cli.md) or [NerdBank.GitVersioning manually using a NuGet package](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/master/doc/nuget-acquisition.md).